# Running code in app regardless of view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want my app to trigger an action when the iPhone's Orientation changes, regardless of where the user is in the app.

I'm using

```
if (([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || 
        ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)) {


}
```

To check for the orientation of the device.

Where do I put this code so that it will always run if the orientation changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your app delegate, register for the `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` notification.

Then in the selector for the notification, you can perform your `if` check.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChange) name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

    // everything else you had in this method
}

- (void)orientationChange {
    if (([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || 
        ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you would like to register a listener for [`UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification).

Comment: in the app delegate? Or where